# Wildfly 18 - How to see stack trace in server.log on WFLYEE0042 - Failed to construct component instance, java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, wildfly

I am getting the following error message when I try to deploy my application on WF18.

This is in the .failed file as well as the server.log file.

What do I need to do to get more information, stacktrace, etc. so I can see what is null?

```
WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException\",
\"jboss.deployment.subunit.\\"policy-ear.ear\\".\\"policy-beans.jar\\".component.ProbeSipFlowRuleEngineHolder.START\" => \"java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException\"
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is not much else than to increase debug output. Configure the root logger to be extremely verbose - this will actually give you tremendous amount of logging. Then mute categories you are not interested in.

This often already helped me figure out the trouble. However if Wildfly does not send a stack trace to the logs you still do not have it.

If you still want to find the call stack, you may want to run Wildfly in debug mode. Create the appropriate JVM parameters so it opens a port for debugging, then use an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans or IntelliJ to connect and set breakpoints. (I think on Windows this could be even easier if the debugger is running on the same machine as Wildfly) The code breakpoint you want could be the constructor of the NullPointerException class.

Once the breakpoint is reached the debugger can show you the call stack directly.